# Select rows where a value is maximum, and a column is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, `products`, that looks along these lines:

```
productID | version | done  
1         | 1       | 2000-01-01  
1         | 2       | NULL  
2         | 1       | NULL  
2         | 2       | 2000-01-01
```

Version is assumed to be increasing.

What I want is a query that returns a ProductID and its highest / current Version, if the Done column for that version is NULL. In plain English, I want all products where the latest version is not Done, and the corresponding version. The goal: among products, find the ones with a new version that have not been "done" / processed yet.

*Note: in the example above, I would expect the query to return ProductID 1, Version 2 only. I do not want the highest not-done version of a product, I want the highest version of a product, if it is not-done. Sorry if the clarification is overkill.*

I wrote a query which appears to do what I want:

```
SELECT productID ProductID, version Version 
FROM products
WHERE done IS NULL
AND version IN (
    SELECT MAX(version)
    FROM products
    GROUP BY productID 
)
```

However, it also appears to not be very efficient. So my question is, is there a better way to approach this query?

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productID ORDER BY version DESC) rn
    FROM products
)

SELECT productID, version
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 AND done IS NULL;
```

### Demo

The CTE above assigns a row number, starting with 1, to latest record for each product, according to version.  Then, we subquery and retain only product records where the latest one happens to not have a value assigned to the `done` column.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are almost correct with your query, what's missing is the correlation between the `productID` of your `subquery` and your main table.

```
SELECT t.productID ProductID, t.version Version 
FROM products t
WHERE t.done IS NULL
AND version IN (
    SELECT MAX(p.version)
    FROM products p 
    WHERE p.productID = t.productID
    GROUP BY p.productID 
)
```

Another solution is to use `join`

```
select t1.* from products t1
inner join
(select max(version) as versionId, productID 
from products
group by productID) t2 on t2.productID = t1.productID and t2.versionId = t1.version
where coalesce(done, '') = ''
```